# Python Pandas Data frame to subplot dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, matplotlib

I am trying to use subplots in matplotlib.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

|  | FY_YYYY_Q | Gender | Head Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017 Q4 | Female | 220 |
| 1 | 2017 Q4 | Male | 200 |

and I need to pass it to the plots parameter as a dictionary:

{'2017 Q4': {'Values': 220, 200}, {'Labels': Female, Male}}

Quite new to Python, so I don't know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

so first things first, the definition of your dictionary is very wrong the correct form should be something like this:

```
dict = {key: value}
# so in your case I fixed it to be like this: 
d = {'2017 Q4': ({'Values': (220, 200)}, {'Labels': ("Female", "Male")})}
# and this is still very counter intuitive, so use this instead:
d = {'2017 Q4':(220,200)}  
# and just make it so in the code the first value is female and the next is male
```

as for how to make a plot from the dictionary use this code:

```
a_dictionary = {"values": (220,210), "labels": ("female","male")}

labels = a_dictionary["labels"]

values = a_dictionary["values"]

plt.bar(labels, values)
```

Comment: Thank you. The thing is, I need a function of some kind to convert a dataframe to dictionary in the format {'2017 Q4': ({'Values': (220, 200)}, {'Labels': ("Female", "Male")})}.

There will be a plot for every year quarter.